# React native module not found in NativeModules if installed using npm

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-ios

I have a private Swift project framework and i wanted to create a React Native wrapper around it and make it available on npm.
So when i create a react native app using : react-native init MyApp and writing the wrapper around the iOS part. I was able to access the the exposed module and exposed methods.
But once i publish this project as an npm package and try to use it in a new project as a dependency and log the NativeModules, i no longer see my module there.
I use `npm install {my-npm-package} --save` 
and link it using `react-native link`.

Can someone help me clarify how this happens ?

Comment: Do you have a Libraries folder in Xcode and see the relevant `.xcodeproj`?

Comment: Yes, after installing the npm dependency i can see it in the `Libraries` folder in XCode.

Answer (score -1):

So to answer my own question, i have found a way to create a bridge and that was possible for me by creating a static library project in iOS and use my library inside it and export the methods i needed.

Comment: Cold you provide an example or a repository to show how to implement it.